# How to change a form value based on tab selection with rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tabs

I have a tab for each day of the week and then subtabs corresponding to event numbers. The problem is I have a form for each event under the subtabs , but I cannot figure out how to associate the tab selection to the form. The day of the week would correspond to the tab selection and the event number would correspond to the tab selection in my form.

pseudocode for the form for

```
form_for(@event) do |f|
   f.hidden_field :day_of_week, value: (based on tab selection)
   f.hidden_field :event_number, value: (based on subtab selection)
   f.time_select :start
   f.time_select :end
   f.text_field :event_location
```

Comment: either you rely on different buttons and do it server side, or use javascript

Comment: didn't even think of mocking tabs with buttons. that should work. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to do,anyway check it out. http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/07/31/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/